# Replace updated iBooks (eBook)

Tags: books, ebook

How can I replace a updated eBook (not via iBookstore) in Apples iBooks-App (on OS X or iOS) without loosing all the associated notes, bookmarks etc.?

For example: Some of O'REILLYs eBooks update quite frequently. I can download the new ePub-Version from their store (NOT Apples iBookstore) and add it to the iBooks-Library. But than I have to delete the old version manually — and loose all the notes, bookmarks etc.. How can I replace the old version with the new one without loosing all my notes etc?

Answer (score 1):

I learned how to export the notes from the iBooks, I'm using to present my seminars at College.
I sherched a way to import them to another eBook and i didn't find, i hope Evernote be a good option to you.

Step 1 – Inside iBooks, you can click on a book.

Step 2 – Click on the book you want to get the highlights from.

Step 3: Click the menu button next to Library at the top

Step 4: Click on “Notes”

Step 5: Click on the arrow at the top right corner and click “Edit notes.”

Step 6: Click Select all (top left corner)

Step 7: Click Share (next to Select all/ Select None) and then Choose Mail

Step 8: Choose Mail and send the email to Evernote or to yourself.

Step 9: Go into Evernote and Sync and your card will appear (usually it goes to the Inbox unless you’ve set it up differently)

Font: [Coolcatteacher](http://www.coolcatteacher.com/export-ibooks-notes/)